# How do I reference the parent/current object in a CakeORM hasMany condition?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, using CakeORM 3.2, I have an object (`Cabinet`), that has `Siblings`, which are other `Cabinets` in the same positions (`Cabinets` that share the same `x`, `y` and `location_id`). In the `hasMany` association, I'm trying to filter out the original object out of the `Siblings`. Here's what I've got

```
class CabinetsTable extends Table { 
    public function initialize(arary $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Siblings', [
            'className' => CabinetsTable::class,
            'foreignKey' => ['x', 'y', 'location_id'],
            'bindingKey' => ['x', 'y', 'location_id']
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've tried adding

```
'conditions' => [
    'cabinet_id <> Cabinets.cabinet_id'
]
```

as an option, but I got the error `Unknown column 'Cabinets.cabinet_id' in 'where clause'`

So what I'm looking for is how do I reference the parent `Cabinet` object in the condition. How can I say `Siblings that don't have the same ID as the parent`?

Comment: So, does the `cabinet_id` column actually exist? In any case you would use the `Siblings` alias if you want to refer to the child table.

Comment: I guess it's not feasable (but hopefully @ndm will provide a solution). IN fact cake generates a query to retrieve all the siblings, and I don't see any way to report the Cabinet.id into the query. I tried something similar, even changing query strategy to subquery it did not worked. I remember cake 2 used to have some magic fields to refer to the other table id something like {$__cakeID__$}

Comment: cabinet_id does in fact exist. I can use it, I just don't know how to reference the parent object

Comment: I misread the question intially... what is `cabinet_id` actually? Is it the primary key column?

Comment: @ndm Each `Cabinet` has the following: A `cabinet_id` which is an integer primary key, a `location_id`, an `x` and a `y`. It has more, but for the purpose of this they aren't relevant. A cabinet is said to be a sibling (In this case, they're half or quarter racks in a datacenter) when they share the same `location_id`, `x` and `y`. So I want to fetch a cabinet, along with it's siblings. But the sibling cabinets always contain the original. So I want to be able to reference the original cabinet in the hasMany condition, so I can say "Has same location, x and y but not the same cabinet_id"

Comment: Yeah, got that... the ORM doesn't support that out of the box, you'll need a custom association and/or eager loader class that makes either the parent query, or the primary keys of the parent query results available to the association conditions. I'll post an answer with an example later on, don't have much time right now.

Answer (score 1):

### Not possible out of the box

As already mentioned in the comments, what you are trying to do isn't possible out of the box.

Currently the ORM will create a new query to retrieve the associated records, and it won't pass any info about the parent/main query to the association conditions which could possibly be used to filter the associated records. The latter however is required, as without the information about the actual parents, it is impossible to exclude them.

### Make the parent query available via a custom association class

The problem could be solved using a custom/extended association class, which makes the parent query available. Alternatively a custom/extended eager loader could be used in combination, which would extract and pass on the primary keys of the parent query results, but that will require reimplementing a bunch of logic, which isn't very nice, so let's skip that at this point.

The custom association class could hook in at for example [**`\Cake\ORM\Association\SelectableAssociationTrait::_buildQuery()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.9/src/ORM/Association/SelectableAssociationTrait.php#L76), which will receive an options array that holds the parent/main query at the `query` key. That value could then be passed to the `conditions` callback, where you could for example extract the primary keys, or use the query as a subquery to filter out the parent `Cabinets` that you don't want to receive as `Siblings`.

### An example

I did something similar some time ago, so I'll just dump a slightly modified version here as an example:

**src/Model/Association/ParentAwareHasMany.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Association;

use Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany;

class ParentAwareHasMany extends HasMany
{
    public function find($type = null, array $options = [])
    {
        $conditions = $this->conditions();
        if (!is_callable($conditions)) {
            return parent::find($type, $options);
        }

        $this->conditions([]);
        $query = parent::find($type, $options);
        $this->conditions($conditions);

        return $query;
    }

    protected function _buildQuery($options)
    {
        $fetcherQuery = parent::_buildQuery($options);

        $callback = $this->conditions();
        if (is_callable($callback)) {
            $fetcherQuery->andWhere(function ($exp, $query) use ($callback, $options) {
                return $callback($exp, $query, $options['query']);
            });
        }

        return $fetcherQuery;
    }
}
```

This should be rather self-explantory, what this class does, is avoiding `Association::find()` to invoke possible callbacks defined in the `conditions` option, and instead invoking it in the `_buildQuery` method, within a wrapped callback that makes the parent query available to the inner callback via a third argument, so the callback defined via the `conditions` option will receive an expression object, the `Siblings` fetcher query, and the `Cabinets` fetcher parent query.

The `CabinetsTable` class would then need to make use of the new association class, for example by overriding `Table::hasMany()`

```
use App\Model\Association\ParentAwareHasMany;

// ...

public function hasMany($associated, array $options = [])
{
    $options += ['sourceTable' => $this];
    $association = new ParentAwareHasMany($associated, $options);
    return $this->_associations->add($association->name(), $association);
}
```

and then you could do the magic in the `conditions` option callback for the `Siblings` association configuration. As mentioned, for example by extracting the primary keys from the conditions:

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\Comparison;
use Cake\Database\ExpressionInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

// ...

$this->hasMany('Siblings', [
    'className' => CabinetsTable::class,
    'foreignKey' => ['x', 'y', 'location_id'],
    'bindingKey' => ['x', 'y', 'location_id'],
    'conditions' => function (ExpressionInterface $exp, Query $query, Query $parentQuery) {
        $ids = [];

        /* @var $where ExpressionInterface */
        $where = $parentQuery->clause('where');
        $where->traverse(function (ExpressionInterface $expression) use (&$ids) {
            if (
                $expression instanceof Comparison &&
                $expression->getField() === 'Cabinets.id'
            ) {
                $ids = (array)$expression->getValue();
            }
        });

        // note that an empty set of IDs will trigger an error

        return [
            'Siblings.id NOT IN' => $ids
        ];
    }
]);
```

by using the parent query as a subquery:

```
'conditions' => function (ExpressionInterface $exp, Query $query, Query $parentQuery) {
    $parentQuery = $parentQuery->cleanCopy();
    // the usage with `IN` requires only a single column to be selected
    $parentQuery->select('Cabinets.id', true);

    return [
        'Siblings.id NOT IN' => $parentQuery
    ];
}
```

or maybe even by executing the query (again) in beforehand and extracting the primary keys from the result:

```
'conditions' => function (ExpressionInterface $exp, Query $query, Query $parentQuery) {
    $parentQuery = $parentQuery->cleanCopy();
    // the contained `Siblings` would cause an infite loop
    $parentQuery->contain([], true);

    $ids = $parentQuery->all()->extract('id')->toArray();

    return [
        'Siblings.id NOT IN' => $ids
    ];
}
```

### Note

Note that these examples are all a little fragile, as a complex parent query might break things, for example when a `beforeFind` callback is involved, when additional conditions rely on specific selected fields, when additional comparision expressions are present that are using the primary key too, etc. But in the end these are just examples that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create Tree Cabinets (Cabinets belongsTo Cabinets) maybe this help you:

**IMPORTANT**: Database **Cabinets** must have field **parent_id**:integer

**Model/Table/CabinetsTable.php**

```
class CabinetsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this -> table('cabinets');

        $this -> addBehavior('Tree');  // <---

        $this -> belongsTo('ParentCabinets', [ // <---
            'className' => 'Cabinets',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        ]);

        $this -> hasMany('ChildCabinets', [ // <---
            'className' => 'Cabinets',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        ]);


    }
}
```

Example **View** method in **Controller/CabinetsController.php**

```
class CabinetsController extends AppController
{
    ...
    public function view($id = null)
    {    

        $cabinet = $this -> Cabinets-> get($id, [
          'contain' => ['ParentCabinets',  'ChildCabinets']
        ]);

        $this -> set(compact('cabinet'));
    }
    ...

}
```

You get some more info in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html (Categores example)

Comment: Thanks, but unforunately our parent object is defined by a combination of three other values, not a parent_id. As their not parent/child and more Siblings. Unforunately just adding the Tree behavior didn't help